# Adding mouselistener to JLabel/JButton inserted in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, jeditorpane, mouselistener

I have a problem where when I try and add a mouselistener to a JLabel or JButton in a JTextPane I get the error "cannot be converted to Mouselistener by invocation conversion".  I would prefer to have the component in a JEditorPane.  I also heard a HyperlinkEvent could be used.

Basicly I want a component that can be right/left clicked in a JEditorPane(preffered)/JTextPane.  Any help would be appreciated

Now it works (sortof) it only recives right clicks and I need to not draw button edges.  Can I underline the button's text?

Example code follows...

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter; 
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent; 

public class jlabeltest extends Applet {

    public void init() {

        jlabeltest editorPaneExample = new jlabeltest();
        editorPaneExample.setSize(550, 300);
//      editorPaneExample.setText("tutorialData.com");
        editorPaneExample.setVisible(true);
    }


    public jlabeltest() {

        JTextPane editorPane = new JTextPane();
        editorPane.setSelectedTextColor(Color.red);
        editorPane.setText("<p color='#FF0000'>Cool!</p>");
        InlineB label = new InlineB("JLabel");  
        label.setAlignmentY(0.85f); 

        label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()   {   

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)   
        {   
        if (e.isPopupTrigger())   
        {   
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello!");
            // do your work here   
        }   
    }   
});  
        editorPane.insertComponent(label); 
        this.add(editorPane); 
    }
}
```

InlineB.java

```
import javax.swing.JButton;

    public class InlineB extends JButton    {

        public InlineB( String caption )    {

            super( caption );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you want the question is everywhere.

But look too underline text of a `JButton` simply set the text of the button with HTML  tags:

```
//added <u></u> to underlone button
InlineB label = new InlineB("<html><u>JLabel</u></html>");
```

as for the left click add a check to your if statement for the `MouseEvent.BUTTON1` or `SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(MouseEvent me)`:

```
//added check for MouseEvent.BUTTON1 which is left click
if (e.isPopupTrigger() || e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
}
```

To not draw the borders of the `JButton` simply call `setBorder(null);` either in the `InlineB` class or on the `InlineB` instance (I did it within the class):

```
   public InlineB(String caption) {
    super(caption);
    setBorder(null);//set border to nothing
}
```

also I see that you dont set the content type of the `JTextPane`, which you should:

```
    //set content as html
    editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
```

I did a small example though I did not use an Applet but its very easy to port:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        initComponents(frame);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents(JFrame frame) {
        JTextPane editorPane = new JTextPane();
        editorPane.setSelectedTextColor(Color.red);

        //set content as html
        editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
        editorPane.setText("<p color='#FF0000'>Cool!</p>");

        //added <u></u> to underlone button
        InlineB label = new InlineB("<html><u>JLabel</u></html>");

        label.setAlignmentY(0.85f);

        label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                //added check for MouseEvent.BUTTON1 which is left click
                if (e.isPopupTrigger() || e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello!");
                    // do your work here   
                }
            }
        });

        editorPane.insertComponent(label);
        frame.getContentPane().add(editorPane);
    }
}

class InlineB extends JButton {

    public InlineB(String caption) {
        super(caption);
        setBorder(null);//set border to nothing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have a problem where when I try and add a mouselistener to a JLabel or JButton in a JTextPane I get the error "cannot be converted to Mouselistener by invocation conversion".

<strike>The object you are passing to addMouseListener() implements the MouseListener interface. Right?</strike> (Just seen the code sample. Mouse adapter seems right).
You now say *Now it works (sortof)*. Does it mean you have corrected that error?

BTW if that is resolved and you have subsequent problems, and they are reusable by the community, then i would advise to open a separate question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48345/what-is-the-etiquette-for-changing-the-substance-of-a-question

> I would prefer to have the component in a JEditorPane.

I guess you mean the component you are listening. Anyway I'm not sure the [JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) is meant to be used as other components' container.

> I also heard a HyperlinkEvent could be used.

[HyperLinkEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/event/HyperlinkEvent.html) is meant for ENTERED, EXITED, and ACTIVATED event types. You are intending to handle Hyperlink events or [mouse events](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html)?

> Basicly I want a component that can be right/left clicked in a JEditorPane(preffered)/JTextPane. Any help would be appreciated

I would advise next time give the scope/context of the question first. I guess you mean you want something (can you be more specific?) on top of a text pane that can be clicked. Anyway I'm surprise you intend to use JEditorPane that way.

Comment: Is there any way I can use HTML in a TextPane?

Comment: @Confident I haven't tried that. But seems to be done in the Swing Tutorial: ["How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)